# How do I send a YAML file as a base64 encoded string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, yaml

I am trying to send a yaml file as a base64 string so that this code works:

```
const response = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/blobs/{file_sha}', {
  owner: 'DevEx',
  repo: 'hpdev-content',
  file_sha: fileSha,
  headers: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${githubConfig?.token}`,
  },
});

const decoded = Buffer.from(response.data.content, 'base64').toString('utf8');
```

In the above code `response.data.content` should have the data.

I have this route:

```
router.get('/repos/:owner/:repo/git/blobs/:file_sha', (req, res) => {
    // TODO: do we need to do anything with the path params?
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    const { owner, repo, file_sha } = req.params;

    const contents = writeUsersReport();
    const encoded = Buffer.from(contents, 'binary').toString('base64');

    res.send(encoded);
});
```

The code is working fine except that the client code expects the base64 string in a property called `content` in the following code:

```
const decoded = Buffer.from(response.data.content, 'base64').toString('utf8');
```

But the string is in `response.data`.
How can I set the `content` property instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about sending a json response containing an object with a `content` property from your server side instead of the encoded string directly?

```
// ...
const encoded = Buffer.from(contents, 'binary').toString('base64');
res.json({content:encoded});
```